How to add actual option value into list item?
Using the select2 javascript for select boxes, it basically hides the actual real select box and gives you a span with a ul li list inside.
However, the li options don't have the actual real value from the original.
Is there a way to make it so the li items for select2 have the real value?
For example this is the original:
<option value="2" selected="" data-select2-id="6">Test Item</option>

Select2 will turn that into:
<li class="select2-selection__choice" title="Test Item" data-select2-id="7"><span class="select2-selection__choice__remove" role="presentation">×</span>Test Item</li>

What I would like, is the real value "2" added into it so I can easily pull it using any outside JS. Something like data-real-value="2" or whatever will do fine.
I'm using it for multi-select, using AJAX to actually pull the results like so:
var $selectclass = $("#select2ajax").select2({
    selectOnClose: true,
    width: '100%',
    ajax: {
      url: "ajaxcall.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function (params) {
        return {
          q: params.term // search term
        };
      },
      processResults: function (data) {
        return {
          results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
            return { id: obj.id, text: obj.text };
          })
        };
      },
      cache: true,
    },
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    containerCssClass: 'class',
    dropdownCssClass: 'class',
    });

If you're wondering why, I simply want to able to detect when someone has mouse clicked on an existing tag that's in the list, to then do something. Select2 doesn't seem to have an option to do that directly, only when stuff is "selected" (added) into the box. Unless I am mistaken.

Can't see that making much sense; the plugin comes with methods to retrieve the selection, and events to handle any changes in the selection dynamically. So why write your own "solution" to an already solved problem?

As far as I can tell, select2 has no functions for detecting if you've clicked something in the list. It has stuff for when selecting (adding to the list) but not just clicking on an item in the list.

I don't get it, what's the difference? Clicking on an item in the list, does select it, doesn't it?

Their events system like select2:select only seems to fire when adding to the list for multi-select. Again, I want to detect all mouse clicks on any existing tags in the list, hence wanting just the plain real value in it.

The change event should fire when you select an option in a single-select. And since clicking does the selecting, I don't see how reacting to clicks on anything inside the list yourself, could be more helpful, or easier. Either way, not sure if you can modify the structure of the list itself - but you can "template" the content of the options, https://select2.org/dropdown - so if you stick the value you need in there, you should be able to fish it out again, in your own custom click handler.

Figured out (finally) a better way. Just add a clickable link into the results inside the actual select2 option, with the real id available. Hope it helps someone.
function formatItem (item)
{
    if (!item.id) {
        return item.text;
    }
    return $('<span>' + item.text + ' (<a href=\"/link/'+ item.id + '\" target="_blank">Item ID Link</a>)</span>');
}

Use that inside the select2 setup options like so:
var $gamesMulti = $("#select2ajax").select2({
    selectOnClose: true,
    width: '100%',
    ajax: {
      url: "search.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function (params) {
        return {
          q: params.term // search term
        };
      },
      processResults: function (data) {
        return {
          results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
            return { id: obj.id, text: obj.text };
          })
        };
      },
      cache: true,
    },
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    containerCssClass: 'class',
    dropdownCssClass: 'class',
    templateSelection: formatItem
    });

